# Symmetric rational functions

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

$x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^3+px+q \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ with real coefficients.

Express through $p,q$ the following symmetric rational function
$$
\sum\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right) = \frac{1}{x_1^2 + x_2^2} + \frac{1}{x_2^2 + x_3^2} + \frac{1}{x_3^2 + x_1^2}
$$
of $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Any tips? I've tried anything that crossed my mind, but I couldn't cope with that.

Comment: Start by expanding $x^3+px+q = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$ and get a formula for $p, q$ in terms of $x_1,x_2,x_3$.  You'll get a third equation from the fact that the $x^2$ term is missing which you can use as well.  Then armed with that try to find a formula for the rational function.  Good luck.

Comment: So far all I have is $-2p=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$ and $-p=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2$

Comment: @Elliot G: I doubt this can be solved without putting $q$ into play.

Comment: @Paul Keseru What has the OP actually tried so far? Where did you get stuck? "Anything that crossed my mind" isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: Alt. hint: $\sum \frac{1}{-2p-x_i^2}=\sum y_i$ where $y_i$ are the roots of [$\text{resultant}(x^3+px+q, x^2y+2py+1, x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28x%5E3%2Bpx%2Bq%2C+x%5E2y%2B2py%2B1%2C+x%29) $= (2 p^3 + q^2) y^3 + 5 p^2 y^2 + 4 p y + 1\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0=x_1+x_2+x_3$, $p=x_1x_3+x_1x_2+x_2x_3$ and $q=-x_1x_2x_3$

Now $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2-2(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)=-2p$.

So your rational expression is

$$\frac{1}{-2p-x_1^2}+\frac{1}{-2p-x_2^2}+\frac{1}{-2p-x_3^2}$$

$$=-\frac{(2p+x_1^2)(2p+x_2^2)+(2p+x_1^2)(2p+x_3^2)+(2p+x_2^2)(2p+x_3^2)}{(2p+x_1^2)(2p+x_2^2)(2p+x_3^2)}$$

Now $x_1^2x_2^2+x_1^2x_3^2+x_2^2x_3^2=(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)^2-2(x_1+x_2+x_3)x_1x_2x_3=p^2$

$$=-\frac{12p^2+4p(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)+(x_1^2x_2^2+x_1^2x_3^2+x_2^2x_3^2)}{8p^3+4p^2(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)+2p(x_1^2x_2^2+x_1^2x_3^2+x_2^2x_3^2)+x_1^3x_2^3x_3^3}$$

$$=-\frac{12p^2+4p(-2p)+p^2}{8p^3+4p^2(-2p)+2p(p^2)+q^2}=-\frac{5p^2}{2p^3+q^2}$$

Comment: Check your expansion of $\prod (2p+x_i^2)$ in the denominator. Also the numerator- you shouldn't be having terms with odd powers of the roots anywhere.

Comment: Should be corrected now

Comment: Now numerator still need fixing. It should be $4p \sum x_i^2$, not $4p\sum x_i$.

Comment: And it's $q^2$ in denominator.  Really, double check your calculations or test with something like $(x-1)(x-2)(x+3)$.